# OOS & SP2019 - Can't open Excel files, other file formats works fine

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2019, office-online-server, oos, wopi

I have the following:

- SP2019 machine, custom, with build nr 16.0.10364.20001
- OOS server, with the latest october CU patch

I've recently deployed the OOS to the SP machine, with no errors. The hosting/discovery works fine on both the machine and from a client computer.

When I go in to a Document library and create a Word file, PowerPoint, OneNote - it works perfectly well. But, when I try to create a Excel file, I get this error:

```
Sorry, something went wrong.
Could you please try that again?

Error Id: a6d5d757-3382-4e4b-83a6-6badfb5fcd15, 2020-10-30 15:33:28Z
```

When I look in the ULS logs, the things I could think of, that could be of relevance is this:

```
WOPI CheckFile - File Author is null for file xxx.xlsx with exception System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.  Parameter name: siteSubscription    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSiteSubscriptionSettings.GetSettings(SPSiteSubscription siteSubscription)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPTenantAdmin.CheckTenantLicenses(SPSiteSubscription siteSubscription, Boolean useCache, String[] licenses)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.Wopi.RunCheckFileInternal(HttpContext context, CommonRequestData requestData, CommonResponseData responseData, String& responseMessage)
```

The Sharepoints Wopizone is set to internal-https. All the servers use a valid wild card cert from an authorized CA.

The WOPIZone looks like this:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-OfficeWebAppsFarm

FarmOU                                       :
InternalURL                                  : https://office.xxx.xx/
ExternalURL                                  :
AllowHTTP                                    : False
AllowOutboundHttp                            : False
SSLOffloaded                                 : False
CertificateName                              : STAR_xxx_2020-2022
S2SCertificateName                           :
EditingEnabled                               : True
LogLocation                                  : C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\OfficeWebApps\Data\Logs\ULS
LogRetentionInDays                           : 7
LogVerbosity                                 :
Proxy                                        :
CacheLocation                                : E:\Cache\d
MaxMemoryCacheSizeInMB                       : 75
DocumentInfoCacheSize                        : 5000
CacheSizeInGB                                : 15
ClipartEnabled                               : False
OnlinePictureEnabled                         : False
OnlineVideoEnabled                           : False
MorphEnabled                                 : True
TranslationEnabled                           : False
MaxTranslationCharacterCount                 : 125000
TranslationServiceAppId                      :
TranslationServiceAddress                    :
RenderingLocalCacheLocation                  : E:\Cache\waccache
RecycleActiveProcessCount                    : 5
AllowCEIP                                    : False
OfficeAddinEnabled                           : False
ExcelRequestDurationMax                      : 300
ExcelSessionTimeout                          : 450
ExcelWorkbookSizeMax                         : 30
ExcelPrivateBytesMax                         : -1
ExcelConnectionLifetime                      : 1800
ExcelExternalDataCacheLifetime               : 300
ExcelAllowExternalData                       : True
ExcelUseEffectiveUserName                    : False
ExcelWarnOnDataRefresh                       : True
ExcelUdfsAllowed                             : False
ExcelMemoryCacheThreshold                    : 85
ExcelUnusedObjectAgeMax                      : -1
ExcelCachingUnusedFiles                      : True
ExcelAbortOnRefreshOnOpenFail                : True
ExcelEnableCrossForestKerberosAuthentication : False
ExcelAutomaticVolatileFunctionCacheLifeTime  : 300
ExcelConcurrentDataRequestsPerSessionMax     : 5
ExcelDefaultWorkbookCalcMode                 : File
ExcelRestExternalDataEnabled                 : True
ExcelChartAndImageSizeMax                    : 1
OpenFromUrlEnabled                           : True
OpenFromUncEnabled                           : True
OpenFromUrlThrottlingEnabled                 : True
PicturePasteDisabled                         : False
RemovePersonalInformationFromLogs            : False
AllowHttpSecureStoreConnections              : False
Machines                                     : {xx-xxx10}
```

I Googled both, but I haven't been able to find a solution yet... One thing i noticed:

In the error message that Excel Online gives, the timestamp is wrong by one hour. It seems the time zone is incorrect?

Comment: What does the OOS ULS log say when you try to create an Excel file?

Comment: Hi! It says like this: WOPI CheckFile - File Author is null for file xxx.xlsx with exception System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.  Parameter name: siteSubscription    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSiteSubscriptionSettings.GetSettings(SPSiteSubscription siteSubscription)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPTenantAdmin.CheckTenantLicenses(SPSiteSubscription siteSubscription, Boolean useCache, String[] licenses)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.Wopi.RunCheckFileInternal(HttpContext context, CommonRequestData requestData, CommonResponseData responseData, String& responseMessage)

Comment: The thing is, the OOS and SP is behind a IDP. Does Excel authenticates different compared to Word, Powerpoint etc?

Comment: OOS uses OAuth, it should not be behind an authenticated service (i.e. use pass-through authentication).